# rmarkdown PDF a3 size

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I tried to add a `classoption: a3paper` but the PDF output is still in A4.

How do I set the knitr PDF to output in A3 size?

```
---
classoption: a4paper
documentclass: article
fontsize: 6pt
geometry: margin=0.5cm
output:
  pdf_document: default
---
```

Comment: `papersize: a3` may work

Answer (score 1):

This may be the easiest answer ever:

Your example asks for a4paper, not a3paper.  When I change that to a3paper, that's what I get.